# Вывод всех событий происходящих на сайте. JS

Tags: javascript, события

Подскажите пожалуйста. Можно ли сделать такую вещь как отлавливание событий. Тобишь когда происходит какое-то событие показывало что это за событие и откуда оно( файл или строка)?

Comment: о каких именно событиях идет речь?

Comment: Зачем? Имеются в виду нормальные клиентские события а не sse, так ведь? Если Вы хотите отлавливать что изменило ноду, в дебаггере можно отлавливать события, изменяющие ноду. Что Вы понимаете под "событиями из файла" я не понял =)

Comment: @Grundy Клик..нажатие клавиши...  и т.д.

Comment: @Утка Клик..нажатие клавиши... и т.д.

Comment: Вы можете выбрать в дебагере ноду, и посмотреть у нее Event Listeners например

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо смотреть в сторону дебаггера, а именно сниппетов, вот на хабре есть [статейка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/192902/)
и еще от [гугла](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/)

И вот еще [сниппет](https://gist.github.com/danburzo/9254630) похожий на ваше решение.
Ну и вот совсем в яблочко [monitorEvents()](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/events)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать дебагер хрома, поставив галочки во вкладке sources на евенты, которые вы хотите слушать. Как этого сделать хорошо написано тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-web-developer